# Using probit regression coefficients to derive probabilities?

Tags: probit

I'm reading a paper [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0cgys2elm1nvmiy/ae2016-2.pdf?dl=0) that uses a Probit Regression. I'm not entirely familiar with how this works. But, I'm wondering if there's a way to use the coefficients from Table 3 to derive the probabilities indicated in Tables 4, 5 and 6. And, if so, how I would do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take text states on page 6 that $pr( < Highschool) = pr(X*\beta + \epsilon < \delta_1)$ where epsilon follows the standard normal distribution. 
Therefore, $$pr( < Highschool) = pr( \epsilon > \delta_1 - X*\beta ) = \\1 - pr( \epsilon < delta_1 - X\beta ) = 1 - \phi^{-1}(\delta_1 - X\beta)$$
where $\phi$ is the CDF of the standard normal distribution. Following these steps and estimation your model you can calculate the probability as follows:
$$\hat{pr}( < Highschool) =1 - \phi^{-1}(\hat{\delta}_1 - X\hat{\beta})$$